# Space of continuous functions form a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be the collection of all continuous real-valued functions defined by 
\begin{equation*}
||f||=\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{\left\vert
f(x)-f(y)\right\vert }{\left\vert x-y\right\vert }
\end{equation*}
for all $f \in X$, then $(X, ||\cdot||)$ is a Banach space.

Comment: @Botond Thanks. Is there any condition/property we can add so that the space will become the Banach space? Actually, in my example, $f(0)\neq 0$, but at some point, say $\bar{x} \in D_{f}$, $f(\bar{x}) = 0$.

Comment: As I mentioned it in my answer, your space is not even a vector space.

Comment: @Botond Thanks, it means that there is no other way to define such type of norm on those functions which are not zero at zero. Right?

Comment: Well, you can simply drop the condition $f(0)=0$, and let the norm be $\lVert f \rVert_0 = |f(0)|+\lVert f \rVert$. We'd need to check it, but I think it will make the space Banach.

Comment: What example do you have in mind, exactly ?

Comment: @D.Thomine   For example, \begin{equation*}
f(x) = x f(ax+(1-a) )  + (1-x) f(bx+(1-b)).
\end{equation*}
We can see that $f(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: I second Botond's suggestion. Drop the condition $f(0)=0$, and work with the norm $\|f\|_\infty+\|f\|_{Lip}$, where $\|\cdot \|_{Lip}$ is the Lipschitz semi-norm (as in your post). You won't get contraction, but you will get strict contraction in the Lipschitz semi-norm + boundedness, and thus convergence to a constant, for the sequence $P^n (f)$, any Lipschitz $f$ and $P$ your operator..

Comment: In the end, there is a subspace $X$ of Lipschitz functions $f$ such that $\int_0^1 f d \mu =0$ which is invariant for your operator, on which $\|\cdot\|_{Lip}$ is a norm, on on which $P$ is a contraction. The condition that the integral of $f$ is zero implies that $f$ vanishes somewhere on $[0,1]$. The problem is that you don't know what $\mu$ is a priori (it depends on $a$ and $b$), so that doesn't help you to define $X$ directly.

Comment: @D.Thomine Thanks for your suggestions. But then how we can prove that, for any $(f_n) \subseteq Lip (p)$ converges to $f \in Lip (p) $. Actually, convergence is okay, but it is hard to prove that $f \in Lip (p) $. Can you please give me the idea of that???

Comment: At that point, if you can't find any reference and don't manage to prove it by yourself, it's probably worth opening a new question. The comments are too short for a full discussion of the subject.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. There are $2$ problems:

- $f(0)=0$ guarantees that $\lVert . \rVert$ is a norm.
- It won't even be a vector space, because if we take a function $f$ with $f(0)=c>0$, and pick a scalar $\alpha < 0$, we get that $\alpha f(0) = \alpha c < 0$, which can't be in the set.

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar What is this an example for?